# Spring Security ProviderNotFoundException when user authentication fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have setup a LDAP Custom Authentication provider similar to the example here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

There is a Login Controller to handle login errors and to check if the user is in an approved list. The Controller calls the Custom authentication provider, the `authenticationManager.authenticate()` method.

When wrong credentials are provided, the Custom Auth provider is called twice. Two exceptions are thrown.

First Exception:

```
31-12-2020 15:42:55.577 [http-nio-9090-exec-6] ERROR c.c.t.a.CustomAuthenticationProvider.hasAccess - test is not authenticated
javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09044E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580 ]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.reconnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.reconnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
        at com.tools.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider.hasAccess(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:65) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.tools.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:32) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) [spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) [spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:502) [spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.tools.web.JwtAuthenticationRestController.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationRestController.java:70) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Second Exception:

```
c.c.t.a.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate - User does not have access
31-12-2020 15:42:55.613 [http-nio-9090-exec-6] ERROR c.c.t.w.JwtAuthenticationRestController.authenticate - Exception logging in user
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:502) ~[spring-security-config-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.tools.web.JwtAuthenticationRestController.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationRestController.java:70) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

This is the Custom provider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (hasAccess(name, password)) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name,
                    password);
            return auth;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasAccess(final String username, final String password) {
    //LDAP access happens here
    }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
public class JwtAuthenticationRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtTokenRequest authenticationRequest)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
         //generate token
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtTokenResponse(token));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException e) {
    //handle exception. set custom response.
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) {   
        try {
            // Check against the approved user list
            //Authenticate the user - Exception thrown here
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("APPLICATION_ERROR", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** Here is the Web Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JWTWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenAuthorizationOncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }   

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity
            .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  
            .cacheControl(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity)  {
        webSecurity
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
                "/authenticate" //authentication path
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
                        "\"login" //Ignore security for Login page.
                )
            .and()
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**");    
    }
```

This happens only when authentication fails due to invalid password. I have checked that the Custom provider throws `javax.naming.AuthenticationException` and returns null for invalis credentials.

Why does Spring throw this exception for failed authentication? The work around is to handle exception in the Controller as a login failure, but still it would be good to understand why this happens.

Comment: Can you provide also your Spring Security configuration ?? Have you added your AuthenticationProvider to the authenticationManager ??

Comment: @JuanBC The Auth Provider is added in the security configuration. I added the security configuration to the question as well.

Answer (score 3):

Have you verified the `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is being invoked from within your controller? That exception pretty clearly came from the `ProviderManager` class. From the `ProviderManager` javadoc:

> If no provider returns a non-null response, or indicates it can even process an Authentication, the ProviderManager will throw a ProviderNotFoundException.

If you've followed the Baeldung example, spring is handling the auth process much further up in the call stack than your controller.

Comment: The CustomAuthenticationProvider is invoked in the Controller for both cases (valid/invalid credentials), based on the logs.

Comment: What logs though? I don't see any logging in your classes.
The partial stacktrace you posted clearly shows the exception originated in at
`ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:227)` That class is a part of spring security. If it's being invoked then it's happening before your controller is ever reached.

Answer (score 1):

Just implementing from `AuthenticationProvider` would not solve your purpose.  You need to register your provider with `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. Hope you have not missed that step on [Register the Auth Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider#java)

#### You could do something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

@Autowired
public MyWebSecurityConfig(CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider){
 this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) throws Exception {
  authBuilder.authenticationProvider(CustomAuthenticationProvider );
}
```

Inject your custom-provide in your `WebSecurityConfig` class and set that field as one of the auth provider.

Comment: Yes. This is done. I added the security config code to the question.